# Debug and Release configurations

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, release, projects-and-solutions

As we all know, in Visual Studio there are two predefined configurations - Debug and Release. I have been using them since I started programming and soon learnt their differences. However recently I had to create my own configurations and now I have a question: Are those two configurations defined/determined solely by their parameters/options from "project options" page? Or does the microsoft compiler treat them in a special way?

My question is this - if I create a new configuration and copy all settings from Debug or Release, will my new configuration be equivalent to the predefined Debug/Release or not entirely?

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are those two configurations
>   defined/determined solely by their
>   parameters/options from "project
>   options" page?

Yes.

> if I create a new configuration and
>   copy all settings from Debug or
>   Release, will my new configuration be
>   equivalent to the predefined
>   Debug/Release ?

Yes it will.

For instance, the debug configuration defines `_DEBUG`, the release configuration enables optimisations, etc.

Comment: I thought so. Asked just to make sure. Thanks

Comment: I liked your answer much more in its first revision :)